# How to enter in new line using windows phone emulator

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8-emulator

How do I enter in a new line using windows phone emulator?
I am trying that using "ENTER" key but not getting in the new line.

Comment: Post your code so we can see why it doesn't work

Comment: In fact that's what I was going to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution

```
AcceptsReturn = "True"
```